# How to pass a long value to a destination fragment using Android Navigation?

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack

I want to implement the [safe-args plugin](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#Safe-args) for Android Navigation.

This works fine for integers and strings, however I am unable to get generated code for long.

Is this possible?

I have tried:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/myFragment"
    android:name="com.x.app.y.MyFragment"
    android:label="fragment_mine"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_mine">
    <argument
        android:name="row_id"
        app:type="long"/>
</fragment>
```

But this generates code for a string.

Here are my options:

[image]

Here is the behavior:

- inferred => `String`
- string => `String`
- integer => `int`
- reference => `int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of types in the UI is the complete list of values that are currently supported by the Navigation Safe Args, so there is no support for longs in the current `1.0.0-alpha01` release.

There is an [existing feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79563966) to add additional supported types, with long being one of the requested types.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian, I have starred the feature request. Is there a way we can get the sources of the plugin (and everything else) so that we can dig ourselves what are the supported types?

Comment: I can confirm that long type works now (tested on alpha08, should work since alpha03), however your Android Studio editor may not support it yet. So you can change it in the nav graph xml in "Text" view mode and the safe args plugin will generate proper classes.